# Value not getting updated when making a calculator

Tags: java, android

I making a simple app in android studio. I have used a Single textview to take in both numbers. I also have buttons made, for the 10 digits, 4 operations and decimal point, and equals.

My app does not read the second number. When I press '=' button, it just displays the first number.
For example, when I put in a number 25, and I press the '+' button, the number gets stored in a float variable res, and the textview is cleared. Now if I put in a second number 11 and I press '=', the output is 25.0

Below, is my code for when I press the + button.

```
    sum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(result.getText()==null)
            {
                result.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                num1 = Float.parseFloat(result.getText().toString());
                res=res+num1;
                result.setText(null);
                num1=0;

            }
        }
    });
```

and below is my code when I press =

```
    equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                result.setText(Float.toString(res));
                res=0;

        }
    });
```

`num1` and `res`, both are float, both initialized to 0.

Edit:- adding the full java code.

```
public class Calculator extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView result;
Button one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,zero,sum,sub,mul,div,decimal,equal;
float num1,num2,res=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
    result = findViewById(R.id.result);
    one = findViewById(R.id.button_one);
    two = findViewById(R.id.button_two);
    three = findViewById(R.id.button_three);
    four = findViewById(R.id.button_four);
    five = findViewById(R.id.button_five);
    six = findViewById(R.id.button_six);
    seven = findViewById(R.id.button_seven);
    eight = findViewById(R.id.button_eight);
    nine = findViewById(R.id.button_nine);
    zero = findViewById(R.id.button_zero);
    sum = findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    sub = findViewById(R.id.button_sub);
    mul = findViewById(R.id.button_mul);
    div = findViewById(R.id.button_div);
    decimal = findViewById(R.id.button_decimal);
    equal = findViewById(R.id.button_equal);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            result.setText(result.getText() + "1");

        }
    });
    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "2");

        }
    });
    three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "3");

        }
    });
    four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "4");

        }
    });
    five.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "5");

        }
    });
    six.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "6");

        }
    });
    seven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "7");

        }
    });
    eight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "8");

        }
    });
    nine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "9");

        }
    });
    zero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "0");

        }
    });
    decimal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + ".");

        }
    });
    sum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(result.getText()==null)
            {
                result.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                num1 = Float.parseFloat(result.getText().toString());
                res=res+num1;
                result.setText(null);
                num1=0;

            }
        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(result.getText()==null)
            {
                result.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                num1 = Float.parseFloat(result.getText() + "");
                res=res-num1;
                result.setText(null);
            }
        }
    });
    mul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(result.getText()==null)
            {
                result.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                num1 = Float.parseFloat(result.getText() + "");
                res=res/num1;
                result.setText(null);
            }
        }
    });
    div.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(result.getText()==null)
            {
                result.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                num1 = Float.parseFloat(result.getText() + "");
                res=res/num1;
                result.setText(null);
            }
        }
    });
    equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                result.setText(Float.toString(res));
                res=0;

        }
    });


}
}
```

Comment: show the other listeners you have written for other buttons?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your should also take the second value from the user and make the calculations in every operator function respectively.

There is logical error in your all the operators functions.
Your should add this line in all the operator whenever the specific function in called.

```
result.setText(num1 - num2 + "");

result.setText(num1 + num2 + "");
```

and so on!!!

2. Your are using a wrong technique by making anonymous function for the operation. Please you switch statement of nested if-else.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading in the value for the second number (right of the operator). Your OnClickListener for the = button does nothing but display res. It doesn't apply the right hand of the operator i.e. the second number

E.g. 1 + 2 = 3

Step 1 press 1
Step 2 press +, the program will get the left of the operator and load it to num1 and add it to res.
Step 3 press 2
Step 4 press =, the program will display res

If you want to see what your program is doing in real time then try using the "Debug" tool where you will be able to step through the program line by line and see what variables are being set to what extra.

Answer (score 0):

use switch case for operators,
let say following are fields;

`public static final int plus = 1
 public static final int minus= 2
 public static final int divide= 3
 public static final int multiply= 4`

and a variable that hold the current operation,

```
int currentOperation;
```

and when some operator button clicked then assign "currentOperation" to that operation
in listener

```
sum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(result.getText()==null)
        {
            result.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            num1 = Float.parseFloat(result.getText().toString());
            res=res+num1;
            result.setText(null);
            num1=0;
            currentOperation = plus //plus is public static final int plus = 1

        }
    }
});
```

and update '=' lisetener with switch statement,

```
equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            num1 = Float.parseFloat(result.getText().toString());
            switch(currentOperation){
                  case plus:
                       res=res+num1;
                       break;
                  case minus:
                       res=res-num1;
                       break;
                  case divide:
                       res=res/num1;
                       break;
                  case multiply:
                       res=res*num1;
                       break;
            }


            result.setText(""+ res);
            num1=0;
    }
});
```